# KnockoutJS Mapping JS to Select Menu

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have this code:

```
     self.States = ko.observableArray();
   self.GetAllStates = function () {
    $.getJSON('/Reference/GetAllStates', function (data) {
        var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        self.States = mapped;
    })
}

     <select class="selectpicker" data-bind="options: States, optionsText: 'State'"></select>
```

Nothing is appearing in the select menu. No errors in the JS console.  I have verified that the server is returning the data.  The server is returning a JSON array.  What am i doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the 'setter' on the observableArray

```
self.States = ko.observableArray();
self.GetAllStates = function () {
$.getJSON('/Reference/GetAllStates', function (data) {
    var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
    self.States(mapped);
});
```

When you setting an observable's value you have to  pass it into a function.  This is the most basic concept in Knockout so I would suggest you have a look at the documentation to get a better understanding of how these observables work.